# Доказать, что множество определения ln(x,y,z) открыто

Tags: математика

Доказать, что множество, на котором определена функция f(x,y,z) = ln(xyz), открыто. Для задания предполагается решение вида: "Рассмотрим множество (0, +inf) - открыто, f непрерывно => f^(-1) (0, +inf) = D(f) - открыто.", используя критерий непрерывности (топологическое определение): "f - непрерывная <=> прообраз любого открытого множества открыт."
Почему тогда нельзя рассмотреть [0, +inf) или, того хуже, R и сказать, что f(R) = D(f)? [0, +inf) и R, очевидно замкнуты, а D(f) не замкнуто.
И вообще из этих трёх утверждений не является ли только f^(-1) (R) = D(f) верным? Но тогда отсюда же следует, что D(f) должно быть замкнуто, а оно таковым не является: возьмём точку x0 = (0, 0, 0) ∉ D(f) и последовательность (1/n, 1/n, 1/n) ∈ D(f) --> x0 => x0 - точка прикосновения не из D(f)

1. Я прочитал этот критерий на сайте [ИТМО](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5). То есть то, что там говорится про замкнутые множетсва - это неправда?
2. Если правда, то не должно быть f^(-1)(R) = D(f) тогда быть и замкнуто, и открыто одновременно? Первое уж точно не верно.

3. Почему прообраз нуля не определён? f^(-1)(0) уж точно содержит точку (1, 1, 1)

P.S. Задание из контрольной по матану второго семестра. Преподаватель очень путано объясняет

Comment: Это вы бы лучше на [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) задали. Там наверняка найдутся люди, которые в этом разбираются.

Comment: R не замкнуто поскольку не содержит бесконечности.

Comment: @Qwertiy, *R* одновременно и замкнуто и открыто. У ТС в голове есть немного каши. Не увеличивайте её количество. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, одновременно вроде не может быть - это ж взаимоисключающие понятия? Замыкание R - это его объединение с двумя бесконечностями (положительной и отрицательной).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не относится к программированию

Comment: @Qwertiy, [Замкнутое множество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE): "Пустое множество ∅ всегда замкнуто (и, в то же время, открыто)." *R* - дополнение пустого множества. И оно тоже и открыто и замкнуто (как дополнение и замкнутого и открытого ∅). Топология такая топология.

Comment: @Qwertiy, топология (даже топология *R*) - это сложно. Сложнее абстрактной алгебры. Полагаться на интуицию не выйдет. Когда вы говорите про объединение *R* с бесконечностями, вы уже ввели две разные топологии, которые не обязаны как-то быть связаны друг с другом.

Comment: Про пустое согласен. Но матанализ у меня в универе был и я помню, что замыкание R - это когда к нему две бесконечности добавляют. Обычно называли "эр с чертой". А вот топологии отдельно у меня не было.

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 2):

Что вам следует сделать - доказать что для любого вещественного числа *w* найдутся три числа, такие что  *ln(xyz) = w*. Например: *x = e<sup>w</sup>, y = z = 1*. Вы показали что что образ функции совпадает с *R*, а *R* - открыто. Функция непрерывна, значит прообраз *R* тоже открыт.

Если вас не устраивает такой подход, постройте область определения функции явно. Октантов всего восемь, четыре из них образуют облась определения. Все четыре открытые множества.